# FirebaseAuth phone verification not reaching complete event on IOS

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter

I'm facing problems with flutter firebase auth package on IOS. In Android it's ok, works just fine, so on IOS Simulator (but in simulator it calls re-captcha). But on iphone physical device, it never gets to the complete event. It fires the code sent event, but not the timeout event or failed auth event neither the completed event.
I set timeout to 30 seconds.

There's no error log, or stack trace or anything simply just don't get there.

```
ntbsbver13:~ rafante$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.9.8-pre.38, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G5019, locale
    pt-BR)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor
      --android-licenses
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.1)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.39.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```